# Ansible stuck at gathering facts when trying to run playbook to configure Mac running macOS Ventura, Apple M1

Tags: ssh, apple-silicon, ventura

I am trying to run Ansible to configure my new mac. The repo that I am using is from [SaiKrishnaMohan7's Github](https://github.com/SaiKrishnaMohan7/ansible_automation). This is my first time using Ansible and I am not as familiar with it. When I run my playbook, it is stuck in the "Gathering Facts" stage, indicating an SSH connection hang. Since it is a local machine I am trying to configure, I am not sure what I am doing wrong and how to debug this.

[image: Screenshot of the Ansible output in Terminal]

Things I have tried:

1. The customary Google search that pointed towards an SSH hang and that is it; Not sure how else to search or fix it
2. I have looked at other folks' Ansible setup, like [Jeff Geerling's Mac setup automation](https://github.com/geerlingguy/mac-dev-playbook) and to my untrained eye things look good
3. I have looked at the previous questions and none seem to be in the ballpark for the challenge I am facing

I have approached this as an opportunity to learn Ansible and learn my machine better in the process. If there is something that I am missing or I am not thinking of, please point me in the right direction.

PS: I tried to create the tag `ansible` but couldn't as I need higher rep in this forum. If someone can maybe create that tag, it will be useful for folks who have the same issue as I